# Value of improper Integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I need help in finding the value of the integral $$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{x^2}{1+x}\right)^{n-1}e^{-tx}dx,$$ where $n$ is a positive integer and $t$ is a positive real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be expressed with a [confluent hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) \begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{x^2}{1+x}\right)^{n-1}e^{-tx}\;dx, = \Gamma(2n-1)U(2n-1;n+1;t)
\end{equation}
for $\text{Re}(t)>0$ and $\text{Re}(n)>\frac{1}{2}$.

One way to show this is a Mellin transform under the integral sign with respect to the parameter $t$ to remove the exponential 
$$
\int_0^\infty \mathcal{M}_t\left[\left(\frac{x^2}{1+x}\right)^{n-1}e^{-tx}\right]\;dx= \mathcal{M}_t[I_n(t)]
$$
$$
\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{x^2}{1+x}\right)^{n-1}\underbrace{\int_0^\infty \;t^{s-1} e^{-tx}dt}_{\Gamma(s)/x^s} \;dx= \mathcal{M}_t[I_n(t)]
$$
then $$
\Gamma(s)\int_0^\infty x^{-s}\left(\frac{x^2}{1+x}\right)^{n-1} \;dx= \mathcal{M}_t[I_n(t)]
$$
$$
\frac{\Gamma(2n-s-1)\Gamma(s)\Gamma(s-n)}{\Gamma(n)}= \mathcal{M}_t[I_n(t)]
$$
then perform an inverse Mellin transform to both sides 
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty} t^{-s}\frac{\Gamma(2n-s-1)\Gamma(s)\Gamma(s-n)}{\Gamma(n)}\;ds=I_n(t)
$$
which when interpreted as a [Barnes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_integral) gives 
$$
I_n(t)=\Gamma(2n-1)U(2n-1;n+1;t)
$$

Comment: Hmmm... I can't decide whether this should be an answer or a comment. You might want to add more detail and derivation, but I won't downvote or upvote for now

Comment: Thanks, I will add some more detail. I interpreted the question as purely asking for the value not the working with it.

Comment: Now that you mention it I suppose that not having a fleshed out answer is alright until the OP decides to show some work and flesh out their answer! +1, though I still recommend some derivation

Comment: I have added a 'fun' derivation which I used. It's probably not the simplest.

Comment: Fantastic. I was skeptical when you put "fun" in quotation marks, but it really WAS fun! Seems fairly simple and straightforward to use the Mellin transform too, given the exponential decay factor. I'd be surprised to see a significantly shorter or simpler proof.